# Pandas interpolate missing values based on other columns criteria

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, missing-data

I have the current dataframe:

| Date | Source | Type | Visits | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | Source1 | Type1 | 100 | 10 |
| 01/01/2020 | Source2 | Type1 | 150 | 5 |
| 02/01/2020 | Source1 | Type1 | NaN | NaN |
| 02/01/2020 | Source2 | Type1 | 125 | 15 |
| 03/01/2020 | Source1 | Type2 | 150 | 18 |
| 03/01/2020 | Source2 | Type2 | NaN | NaN |
| 04/01/2020 | Source1 | Type2 | 150 | 25 |
| 04/01/2020 | Source2 | Type2 | 120 | 05 |

What I'd like to do is a simple .interpolate() for the missing data however I need to group it by the Source and Type to keep the data as accurate as possible rather than basing it on the above and below rows which aren't relevant.

I've got to this stage:

```
df_fixed = df[['Source','Type','Visits','Sales']].loc[(df['Source'] == 'Source1') & (df['Type'] == 'Type1')].interpolate()
```

Which does the first step but can't get any further and feel like there's an easier way.

What would be the most elegant way to complete this?

Comment: I think you need `df.groupby(['Source', 'Type']).apply(pd.DataFrame.interpolate, limit_direction='both')`?

Answer (score 0):

One idea is change the NAN - of median or mean.

```
df['visits'].fillna(df['visits'].median(), inplace=True)
df.fillna(df.mean())
```

[image]

---

Edit:

If You decide to use .interpolate() - so

> need to group it by the Source and Type:

You can use **[groupBy()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)** - method for group by Source and Type:

```
df.groupby(['Source', 'Type'])
```

Comment: I'm planning on using the .interpolate() option as it seems the best option for the dataset as it's trended over time. However currently when I do this, it's basing it on the rows above and below which aren't relevant to the missing value rows.

Comment: The group by option is what I'm hoping to achieve it by however I can't seem to group by, complete the interpolation then ungroup the data back to the original format if that makes sense?